# Opening app store page before having app in the store

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I use this link to open app store page, that doesn't exists, because I haven't send app for moderation yet. So, when I click the button, nothing happens. Must it be so? If it's OK, how does it affect the moderation ?

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.com/app/MyAppNameWithoutSpaces"]];
```

Comment: Shachar has the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "nothing happens" what do you mean ?

If the browser opens with the link you provided and you just get a blank page with an alert saying that page don't exist that in my opinion your good.

Whenever I add this feature it works just like that.. once your app is approved and available the link should work fine.

Just make sure its the right link.

Comment: @Shachar OK, I used this method, because some people on stack overflow said it must redirect to app store without opening safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this info in the comment session to the moderation team when uploading the app.

Or you can remove this feature for now and upload another version when you have the URL ready.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Apple will approve your app as is. You can try the comment as Andre mentioned, but I would suggest removing the functionality until that app is in the store. I take it you are create App A to have a link to App B and neither are in the store?